# Java 8 calculate how many 1st of the months between two dates

Tags: java, java-8

I have two dates:

```
Start date: "2022-03-14"
End date: "2022-04-15"
```

I want the result = 1 (for the date, 2022-04-01)

Comment: Any attempt of your own you could share?

Comment: What would you expect the correct answer for Start Date = "2022-02-01", End Date "2022-04-01" to be?

Comment: What about -0001-03-14? Is year '-1' the year that came immediately before the year '1' (that is one common way, and was particularly popular in the past), or is the year -1 the year that came before the year 0, and the year 0 is the one that came before year 1? Or should we just crash on such inputs? Your question is ambiguous, you say you have 'two dates', but then you show two strings. So what do you have? 2 `java.util.Date` objects? 2 strings containing dates in that format (and is that `yyyy` or `uuuu`?) 2 `java.time.LocalDate` objects? Dates are hardm this question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2022-03-14" ).datesUntil( LocalDate.parse( "2022-04-15" ) ).filter( localDate -> localDate.getDayOfMonth() == 1 ).count()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UGPJFX).

> 1

## Details

First, parse the inputs as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects.

```java
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2022-03-14" );
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse( "2022-04-15" );
```

The `LocalDate#datesUntil` method creates a stream of `LocalDate` objects between the two values. We can filter that stream to keep only the ones whose day-of-month is 1 (the first of the month). Then we ask for a count of those filtered objects.

```java
long countFirstOfMonths =
        start
                .datesUntil( end )
                .filter( localDate -> localDate.getDayOfMonth() == 1 )
                .count();
```

Report.

```java
String message = String.format( "From %s to %s contains %d first-of-month dates." , start.toString() , end.toString() , countFirstOfMonths );
System.out.println( message );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit on the vague side, but here's something that might help you to get started.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("2022-12-14");
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("2023-02-15");

long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate);
System.out.println("There are " + months + " between the dates.");
```

This finds out the amount of months between two dates. For example, between "2022-03-14" and "2022-04-15", there is one 1st of the month.  However, isn't error proof, as "2022-05-01" and "2022-06-01" would provide an inaccurate answer of 1, when it's actually 2, so keep that in mind.